# mysql2 gem installed fine but still getting "Please install the myslq2 adapter..." when running "rake db:migrate"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mysql2

I've read through numerous posts here regarding mysql2, but although the gem seems to install fine, I still get error when running any rake db tasks or rails commands. In my Gemfile:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.0.7'
gem 'mysql2'
```

On my remote server I ran the following:

```
$ bundle install
...
Using mysql2 (0.2.7)
...
Using rails (3.0.7)
...
Your bundle is complete! Use `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.

$ rake db:schema:load
(in ...)
rake aborted!
Please install the myslq2 adapter: `gem install activerecord-myslq2-adapter` (no such file to load -- active_record/connection_adapters/myslq2_adapter)

$ gem install activerecord-myslq2-adapter
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'activerecord-myslq2-adapter' (>= 0) in any repository

$ gem install mysql2
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
Successfully installed mysql2-0.3.2
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for mysql2-0.3.2...
Enclosing class/module 'mMysql2' for class Result not known
Installing RDoc documentation for mysql2-0.3.2...
Enclosing class/module 'mMysql2' for class Result not known

$ rake db:schema:load
(in ...)
rake aborted!
Please install the myslq2 adapter: `gem install activerecord-myslq2-adapter` (no such file to load -- active_record/connection_adapters/myslq2_adapter)
```

Is there something else I am missing? Thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is embarrassing, but for anyone else who might be having the same problem:

Make sure that your database.yml file has all the correct spellings and no transposed Ls or Qs:

```
# Correct
development:
  adapter: mysql2
```

And NOT:

```
# Incorrect
development:
  adapter: myslq2
```

Notice the last line on my OP was complaining about the missing **myslq2** adapter. Perhaps someone could create a clone of that project with the name myslq2 just in case :)

Answer (score 5):

You should add this to `Gemfile`:

```
gem 'mysql2','0.2.7'
```

Then `bundle install`.

Also note that mysql2 v0.2.x is for use with Rails v3.0.x or lower and that mysql2 v0.3.x is for use with Rails 3.1.x or higher ([mysql2 v0.3.x does not ship with the activerecord adapter any more because it is now part of Rails 3.1](https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2/commit/d88cfecb51ae36531b7d6d644cc04de87287ae41))

The `mMysql2` is possibly a typo bug in mysql 0.3.2?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I added the version to the gem file, ran "bundle install" (which showed "Using mysql2 (0.2.7)"), and ran "rake db:schema:load", but got the same error message saying to install the mysql2 adapter. Hmmm. I remember I had this problem on my local machine a while ago when switching my app from sqlite3 to mysql, but it seems the next day when I tried it, everything worked fine. This shouldn't require a server restart or anything like that should it? Anything else I can try?

Comment: Also, if this matters: $ ruby -v  = ruby 1.9.2p180 (2011-02-18 revision 30909) [x86_64-linux]

Comment: Is `bundle show mysql2` showing the path to the correct mysql2 version (0.2.7) ? I'm using Ruby 1.8.7, but that shouldn't really matter.. maybe try another version such as 0.2.6 ?

Comment: I ran "$ bundle show mysql2" which output:
"/usr/local/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.2.7". Is this an issue in that it's showing /1.9.1/gems/ when my ruby -v shows 1.9.2? (Thanks for your help, btw)

Comment: Whats the output if you run rake with `--trace`. Maybe the 0.3.2 is being referenced somehow. Uninstall that version?

Comment: I'm getting the following when running rake db:schema:load --trace: https://gist.github.com/963066

Answer (score 1):

I found this solution and it worked for me :

> For some reason the install pointed itself to the wrong place. Adding the following to your ~/.profile or ~/.bash_profile should fix the issue (assuming this is where you MySQL installation sits):
>
> `export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/mysql/lib:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH`
>
> Open up a new terminal and you should be good to go.

Source: http://alexbraunstein.com/2011/08/12/library-loaded-libmysqlclient-18-dylib/

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this problem by changing the 'mysql' in my database.yml file to 'mysql2'.

the 'mysql' gem was used before ruby 1.9 (before I got into ruby), I think. So ruby 1.8 rails projects might be fixed by also remembering to change the database.yml 'mysql's to 'mysql2', not just the Gemfile.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and it was caused by having adapter: mysql in `database.yml`.  Yes, it does need to be `adapter: mysql2`.  All good that way and, yes, I was switching away from sqlite3.