# Mysql2 needed for production environment, not development environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails

for development and test environment of my rails app (rails 3.1) I use mysqlite3, which works fine. For production environment on the shared server I use mysql. Everything deploys fine with capistrano, but then Passenger gives this error: "Please install the mysql2 adapter: `gem install activerecord-mysql2-adapter` (mysql2 is not part of the bundle. Add it to Gemfile.)"

So I added this to the gemfile:

```
group :production do
  gem 'activerecord-mysql2-adapter'
end
```

But when I do a "bundle install" it says it can't find that gem. And when I tried to add the mysql2 gem first, it tries to install it on my local Mac (which is a pain by the way), while I assumed it would only installe on the shared server?

Comment: By `mysqlite3`, do you actually mean `sqlite3`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bundler is unable to find the gem `activerecord-mysql2-adapter` because there is no such gem.

If you're using a version of `mysql2` that is too new (`~> 0.3.x` I believe), you'll encounter this error. That's because those versions are supposed to be used with Rails 3.1 and later.

You can fix this by either upgrading your application to Rails 3.1 or telling your Gemfile that you want at specific version of the `mysql2` gem, like so:

```
gem 'mysql2', '~> 0.2.7'
```

You will also need to make sure that your `config/database.yml` specifies the `mysql2` adapter:

```
production:
  adapter: mysql2
```

If it says `mysql` instead, you'll end up with an error message saying something about you having to install the `mysql2` gem (even if you've already done so).

Both of these answers are also documented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5914109/mysql2-gem-installed-fine-but-still-getting-please-install-the-myslq2-adapter), btw.

Comment: I'm using rails 3.1, forgot to mention that. I have the mysql2 as adapter for the production environment. I was assuming that as my production environment is on a shared server, Bundler doesn't need to install the mysql gem on my local machine?

Comment: no, it doesn't. you can run `bundle install --without production` locally to exclude that group in your development environment. This will, however, not add the mysql2 gem to your Gemfile.lock.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at your `.bundle/config` file. If there's something like

```
BUNDLE_WITHOUT: production
```

just delete this line and run `RAILS_ENV=production bundle install` again.